# Поиск на jquery - выделение найденного текста

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть:Добрый день! Имеется простенькая форма поиска на бутстрапе. Ищет статьи с совпавшим текстом. Скрин ниже.
Цель:Нужные статьи-то он находит, а вот текст найденный не выделяет. Нужно реализовать выделение.
Код, реализующий поиск:

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.article').filter(function() {
    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

`#search` соответственно это айди инпута поиска, а `.article` - класс статей, в которых ищет текст. Что сюда дописать нужно, чтобы появлялось выделение найденного текста в статьях? Хелп ми плиз!
Попробовал пошариться в нэте - не очень успешно.
Пишу первый раз здесь, надеюсь хоть кто-то прочитает))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так. В вашем случае должно работать.

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.article').filter(function() {

        var is_compare = $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);

        if(is_compare) {
            $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
        }

        return is_compare;

    });

});
```

Comment: Попробовал, теперь только он красит не найденный текст, а бэкграунд всей статьи. Т.е. все в статье кроме изображения красится в желтый бэкграунд

Comment: я вам подпросил "саму идею" как это делается на практики, а вы смотрите сами уже как доработать нужно под свои нужды

Comment: Да, благодарю!)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так ещё можно, как вариант. Только неплохо ещё проверку вставить на наличие "<font class="sot">" для изменяемых элементов.

```
<style>
    .sot {
        color:#F00;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $('#search').on('keyup', function() {
        var value = "123";
        $('.article').filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
            nt = $(this).text();
            $(this).html(nt.replace(value, "<font class=\"sot\">"+value+"</font>"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Перед каждым вызовом нужно убирать предыдущие вставленные теги. И font давно устарел, используют `span`

Comment: Попробовал реализовать, работает, только вот изображение статьи исчезает, остается только блок с найденным текстом в этой статье, также исчезают стили заголовка в тексте и стили всего текста. И найденное слово "раздвигает" текст и становится на отдельную строку. Все едет в общем))

Comment: Нужно смотреть на стили. Да, "font" тут явно лишний и нужно использовать "span", а потом уже в консоли смотреть какие стили меняют отображение контента.